# When trying to animate listview's row view, I want to animate the offscreen rows too

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

What I'm trying to do is to have all the rows in the listview translate to the right in order to expose a checkbox for multi-selection. And actually it works ok beside this:

- the animation on the visible rows is ok, but there are like **2-3 rows, created in advance** (before starting to recycle them) so the scroll is smooth, **in which the translation starts when those become visible** (onscreen).

I know this is normal behaviour but could there be any way to have those rows translated before they become onscreen? I was thinking of something like setting the translation time to those to 1 but can't know where the returned view will be used by the list.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_conversation, null);
    }

    final AQuery aq = new AQuery(view);
    // multiSelect
    if(multiSelect) {
        aq.id(R.id.row);
        if((int) aq.getView().getX() == 0) {
            animate(aq.getView())
                    .translationX(marginLeftWhenMultiSelect)
                    .setDuration(300);
        }
    } else {...
```